# Series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\left(2\cdot2^n+kx\right)^{-z }$ with $\Re(z)>1$ and $ x\geq -2$ real

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Assume that $\Re(z)>1$ and $x\in \mathbb R$ with $ x\geq -2$.

Is it possible to compute $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac1 { \left(2\times2^n+kx\right)^z }\ ?$$

Comment: own thoughts?$ $

Comment: @tired : yes, but it is very important to understand the behavior of
$\zeta $ function.